# Javascript: how to run sequentially slow functions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, sequential

I am not an experienced Javascript programmer but I find it very difficult to execute 2 time-consuming functions in the row.

I have spent some days on studying promises or async/await but not success so far.

```
console.log("synch 1");
slowFunction1();
slowFunction2();
console.log("synch 2");
```

Most examples describe get json functions,setTimeOut etc. But in my case I have to do heavy mathematical calculations and the sequential execution is required. How could I do this?

Comment: Did you research of Promise?

Comment: you want run slowFunction1 and slowFunctuion2 simultaneously?

Comment: Note that even if you run slow functions asynchronously, they would most likely not be executed in different threads. So they won't run parallel - they'd still be executed sequentially but you might get a bit of "breathing room" between them. This could allow a UI to catch up and update between the calls, for example. Is that what you are after, or do you want to run them in parallel?

Comment: This article may be of help: [Parallel programming in JavaScript using Web Workers](https://itnext.io/achieving-parallelism-in-javascript-using-web-workers-8f921f2d26db)

Comment: I always prefer a downvoting reason to the question/answer. It really helps people to grow in community with a confidence. Reason help to prevent mistakes in future

Comment: @SatyamPathak I agree. It's especially annoying when it's done to new users - a veteran might understand what (if anything) is wrong to attract a downvote but a new user would not necessarily understand that. Also, it seems like some people just downvote stuff for the sake of it - I've found no other explanation, as I see downvotes on otherwise good questions answers with no problems or no problems that really warrant a downvote (e.g., some minor grammar or typo fixes needed).

Comment: Could you please show us whats inside of those functions (in other words: what you are trying to do), and how that behaves, and which behaviour you expected instead ...

Comment: @enno.void: No, sequentially

Comment: I realize this is an old question at this point but I am really confused by the question and answers. You are asking how to run them sequentially. The code you provided in the question will run them sequentially and nothing after it will run until they are done. Yet all the answers assume you want to run them async and none of them solved your problem. I think there is a misunderstanding going on.

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your functions in a promise like this, and only resolve when you want the code to continue:

```js
function slowFunction1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
  })
}

function slowFunction2() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
  })
}


console.log("synch 1");
slowFunction1().then(() => {
  slowFunction2().then(() => {
    console.log("synch 2");   
  });
})
```

This code should wait 1 second for each function before it console.log()'s "synch 2"

**OR**, you could use async/await instead of using .then(), like this:

```js
function slowFunction1() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
  })
}

function slowFunction2() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)
  })
}

async function main() {
  console.log("synch 1");
  await slowFunction1()
  await slowFunction2()
  console.log("synch 2");   
}

main()
```

Comment: I think I can understand better async/await but what puzzles me is where exactly I should  insert all mathematical functions in slowFunction2() for example. Just above return new Promise?

Comment: I would have to know what your mathematical functions are first :p

Comment: The functions are like CalculateAverage(array[20000]); CalculatePearsonChiSquareTest(array[20000]); I have managed to run them sequentially with no problem and they are all running in a function doCalculations(array[2000]). Now I want to insert doCalculation() in your example above and I am confused with the syntax. This function has to finish up before moving to the next step.

Comment: I would recommend creating another question with the code for each function, and ask there. It is a bad idea to try and solve a problem that I have very little knowledge of in the comments section. If you would like, you can create a question and send me the link here and I'll have a look at it

Comment: What confuses me is the usage of setTimeout in the return:   return new Promise(resolve => {  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000)  }). I understand that it is used to simulate a slow function. If I have a mySlowFunc() instead how would this be inserted in your example?

Comment: It depends on what the function is. If the function isn't asynchronous, then you don't need to worry about promises and the lot, but if it is, the easiest way to make your code work in order is to return a promise from your slow function, and use a .then() to access the returned value. By the sounds of it, you **don't** need to use promises, if you are just executing arithmetic code.

Comment: The only reason I used setTimeout was to wait a second before returning a value, you would not use this in your code. You could remove the setTimeout and it would still execute sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're trying to achieve and what the environment is. I will assume the slow function is blocking and you're going for the main thread not to be blocked during execution. Assuming you are talking about:

1. Web:

   - Web workers would be your best bet (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Some example code would be:

```
var myWorker = new Worker('file-containing-slow-code.js');
myWorker.postMessage({execute: 'slowFunction1'});
myWorker.onmessage((msg) => {
  const {result, functionExecuted} = msg.data;
  console.log(result);
});
```

```
//contents of file-containing-slow-code.js
onmessage = function(e) {
  var result = funcs[e.data.execute]();
  postMessage({result, functionExecuted: e.data.execute});
}

const funcs = { 
  slowFunction1: () => {
    // do slow stuff;
  }
};
```

2. Node.js

   - Using child processes (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process)

Comment: I don't mind blocking, I want a specific function to be fully executed before moving on, but can't make it with await/async or promise.

Answer (score 0):

You got this right,you are trying to achieve a `asychronous` task.

**Asynchronous Task**

A task which will take some time to complete.

Way 1 - **Callbacks**

You need to give a callback to your further task.
Let me give you an example.

```js
function myHugeTask(callback) {
  // I need to do my task
 console.log('Hey I am  first task')
 callback() 
}

const someTaskWhichINeedToExecuteLater = () => {
 console.log('Hey I am after the first task')
}

myHugeTask(someTaskWhichINeedToExecuteLater)
```

Way 2 - **Promises**

Promises is like a real world promise. If I promised you then I will either complete it or reject it.

Let see

```js
const myHugeTaskPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  // Do my huge  task no matter how much time it takes
  console.log('I will complete first')
  resolve()
})

myHugeTaskPromise.then(()=>{
  console.log('Need to done when my promise get fulfilled')
})
```

Comment: I get: 'Need to done when my promise get fulfilled'
0
1
2
3
4 When I run : const myHugeTaskPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
  // Do my huge  task no matter how much time it takes
   slowFunction();
   resolve();
})

myHugeTaskPromise.then(()=>{
  console.log('Need to done when my promise get fulfilled')
})


function slowFunction() {
  for (let i = 0, p = Promise.resolve(); i < 5; i++) {
    p = p.then(_ => new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(i);
        resolve();
      }, Math.random() * 1000)
    ));
  }
}

Comment: I am sorry, it does not work. I tried a functions that uses timeout and generates numbers  in the   // Do my huge  task no matter how much time it takes and I take: Hey I am  first task'
4:47:15.056 PM
'Hey I am after the first task'
0
1
2
3
4